# WANDB Getting a run id based on tag

Tags: python, metadata, wandb

## Context

Hi!

In `wandb` I can download a model based on a tag (`prod` for example), but I would like to also get all metrics associated to that run by using tags.

The problem is that I don't know how to a get specific run ID based a tag.

## Example

Using the code bellow we can extract a run summary metrics, but setting run IDs is setting me back.

So if I can get run IDs based on tag or just explicitly download metrics  with another API call, like with a special sintax in `api.run`, that would be great! In the code example bellow I would like to use the `what_i_want_to_use` string to call the API instead of `what_i_use`.

```
import wandb
from ast import literal_eval
api = wandb.Api()

what_i_use = "team_name/project_name/runID_h3h3h4h4h4h4"
# what_i_want_to_use = "team_name/project_name/artifact_name/prod_tag"

# run is specified by <entity>/<project>/<run_id>
run = api.run(what_i_use)


# save the metrics for the run to a csv file
metrics_dataframe = run.summary
print(metrics_dataframe['a_summary_metric'])
```

By running through the docs I didn't find any solution so far. Any ideias?

[wandb public api run details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWl3I.png)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to filter runs by tags as well. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/python/public-api/api#runs):

```
You can filter by config.*, summary_metrics.*, tags, state, entity, createdAt, etc.
```